# Is it possible to change underlying database source in Entity Framework model dynamically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my application,I have generated an EF model from an existing database.My problem is that in our environment we have a separate database for each month data consisting of the same tables and structure.( e.g Database_012018 , Database_022018...etc) .
Is it possible to use the same EF model to query different monthly underlying databases using some parameter?

Hope there is a solution for this as I'm new to working with EF, and I don't know if this can be achieved. Thanks.

Edit: This is a windows forms application and EF 6.

```
This is my context class code which is generated automatically :

public partial class InSight_BNK_11802Entities1 : DbContext
{
    public InSight_BNK_11802Entities1()
       : base("name=InSight_BNK_11802Entities1")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can do that by passing connection string to the context object at runtime. Can you share your code of context class?

Comment: @MickyD he clearly wants to dynamically change the DB at runtime, so changing app.config is not an option.

Comment: Which EF version do you use? Code-First or Model-First? Do you need to dynamically query multiple tables with a single EF query?

Comment: where is ASP.NET, IIS or WCF mentioned on the question?

Comment: I expressed it wrongly, as he wants to change it at runtime, writing back and reloading the app.config *is* actually an option, but a really bad one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166062/discussion-between-thepirat000-and-mickyd).

Comment: @thepirat000 I used EF designer from database,and I need to be able to change database source in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As @ChetanRanpariya suggested, and assuming the following:

- Using EF 6 with model-first approach (edmx)
- You want to query a single database each time

You could pass the connection string with a different `initial catalog` each time you query your `DbContext`, for example:

```
string database = "Database_012018";

var cnnString = $"metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source=.;initial catalog={database};integrated security=True\"";

using (var ctx = new BlogsEntities(cnnString))
{
    ctx.Blogs.Where(...);
}
```

If you use the auto-generated DbContext (in my case `BlogsEntities`), you'll probably need to add a constructor that accepts a connection string. You can do this in a different .cs file, as a partial class, to avoid touching the auto-generated file:

```
public partial class BlogsEntities : DbContext
{
    public BlogsEntities(string cnnString)
        : base(cnnString)
    {

    }
}
```

## UPDATE

Note your connection string must include the metadata EDMX reference (in my case the edmx file is called `Model.edmx`). Just borrow your current connection string from your config and change the `initial catalog` value.

Comment: I did. But it said to me my vote up will be recorded but won't shown to public because I still have not reached some level.